# Getting Parent Member from Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, lambda, expression

I have an `Expression` that is used to get a list of items from my `Model` for my View.
What I want to do, is given the `Expression` for the `List`, can I go backwards upward on the `Expression Tree` one level to get the parent node?

Let's say this is my view model:

```
public class MyModel {
   public MyClass myClass { get; set;}
}
```

...

```
public class MyClass {
   public List<string> MyList { get; set;}
}
```

I have an `HtmlHelper` that takes an `Expression` as follows to render a list to the page:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RenderList(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>>> dataExpression)
{   
     var list = dataExpression.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);

     ...

     return MvcHtmlString.Create(...);
}
```

I call my helper as follows:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.MyModel
@Html.RenderList(m => m.myClass.MyList)
```

This all works fine, my question is, can I take the given `Expression` which points to the `List<string>` and get it's parent node (`MyClass`) then compile it against my `Model` to get it's value. So the equivalent of this `Expression`:

```
m => m.myClass
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
// This gets the correct expression
var exp = ((MemberExpression)this._dataExpression.Body).Expression;
// Create a parameter representing the type of the Model ?
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
// Create lambda
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, dynamic>>(exp, parameter);
// Try and compile against the view model
var obj = lambda.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
public static IHtmlString RenderList<TModel, TItem>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TItem>>> dataExpression
)
{
    var parentEx = ((MemberExpression)dataExpression.Body).Expression;
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, object>>(parentEx, dataExpression.Parameters[0]);
    var value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(lambda, html.ViewData).Model;

    ...
}
```

Obviously you should add a minimum of error checking to this code which I have intentionally omitted here for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same parameter expression in your new lambda expression:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyModel, dynamic>>(exp,
    this._dataExpression.Parameters);
```